# What is the best way to disable all internet abilities on a laptop?

Tags: laptop, internet-connection

This laptop has LAN (built in) and a wifi card. I was thinking I could just remove the wifi card - but the LAN chip is more of a problem. I don't want a fix to be apparent so I was thinking I could install the wrong driver, disable the device, remove the TCP/IP driver, and edit the hosts config.

Any other options? I don't really want to permanently harm it.

*Back story: Windows XP machine used for writing, needs to be left somewhere where people might "borrow" it for online browsing and mess it up.*

Comment: An option: [Jacklock](http://www.we-supply.com/browse.cfm/rj45-jack-security-lock:-black-1-each-/4,10598.html).  Never used it nor am I sure it'll fit the majority of RJ45's, but it's an option at least.

Comment: How secure/locked-down do you need to make it? Can you simply disable the network adapters in *Device Manager*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the BIOS and see if you can disable onboard Ethernet and LAN.  Set a BIOS password.

This does not prevent the user from installing another USB or PCMCIA-based LAN or WLAN card, but if you don't leave an administratior login open on the system you should be OK (drivers will be needed) unless someone goes so far as to  run a liveCD or boot off of another disc.  If you want to go so far as to prevent that, BIOS boot options again are likely the best way (even if you remove your optical drive someone could connect a USB one).

Comment: +1 Very nice answer, I completely forgot that it can be controlled by most BIOS.  I believe you can disable USB ports via the BIOS as well.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to go into TCP settings and instead of automatically getting the IP addresses via DHCP, change it to specific settings.  Then set the Default Gateway to some bogus IP address.  The network adapters then will look Enabled and working in Network Connections.

Set the IP Address and Subnet Mask to something real if you want to connect to an internal network.

However, any user with admin rights and the knowledge to make the changes can easily bypass this.

Answer (score 0):

Define bad routes to override 0.0.0.0/0 default route.

```
ip route add 0.0.0.0 mask 128.0.0.0 127.0.0.1 -p
ip route add 127.0.0.0 mask 128.0.0.0 127.0.0.1 -p
```

You'll be able to communicate with devices on the LAN but not the internet at large due to the bogus routes.